# Finding text of an element within a HTML string

Tags: jquery, ajax

I am trying to load products number with AJAX. The code will be more complicated but to simplify the question, there is a block on the /category-one/

```
<div id="products-count">6</div>
```

Let's say, I am on any other page, home for example. I am trying to get that "6". I have tried the following but the alert is empty.

```
var url = '/category-one/';

$.ajax({
    url: url,
    success: function(data) {
        var $fullContent = $('#products-count', data)
        var text = $fullContent.text();
        alert(text);
    }
});
```

What is wrong with this code?
Thank you for your help in advance.

Comment: So what is in data?

Comment: There must be something wrong with my code, but I hoped, the content is actually the text inside, here "6"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that for a contextual selector to work the second argument of the jQuery object needs to be an Element or jQuery object, or a selector string ([ref](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#jQuery1)). Given the context of your code, I would presume `data` holds HTML, not a selector.

To fix the issue you can provide `data` to a jQuery object and then `find()` the required element:

```js
var url = '/category-one/';
$.ajax({
  url: url,
  success: function(data) {
    let $data = $(data);
    let $fullContent = $data.find('#products-count');
    let text = $fullContent.text();
    console.log(text);
  }
});
```